# How to make SwiftUI interface scalable?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My SwiftUI Interface looks different on each iPhone model. I want to ask for best practice of creating scalable(or at least adaptable) interface with SwiftUI.

For example:

```
struct NewStruct: View {
    @State var someState = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer().frame(width: 25)
                Text("Text1")
                Spacer()
            }
            Button(action: {
                someState = !someState
            }, label: {
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).fill(Color.white).frame(width: 350, height: 60)
                    HStack {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer().frame(maxWidth: 10)
                            Image(systemName: "bolt.fill").resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 35, height: 35).cornerRadius(30).padding()
                            Text("Text1").foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            Spacer()
                            Spacer(minLength: 30)
                            Image(systemName: "poweroff").resizable().frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                            Image(systemName: "power").resizable().frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                            Spacer().frame(maxWidth: 30)
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

| How it should look like (iPhone 12) | Buggy view(iPhone 12 Pro Max) |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: Just don't hardcode layout.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide some techniques how I can avoid this? Would be much appreciate!

Comment: @SmilingKnight just don't use fixed frames, and then SwiftUI will automatically scale your interface. Don't use GeometryReader either. Also if my answer worked, can you press the green checkmark to accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here — setting a fixed frame of `350` isn't going to scale well to other screen sizes:

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).fill(Color.white).frame(width: 350, height: 60)
```

Also, instead of `ZStack`, use [`.background`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(alignment:content:)) — `ZStack` are usually used for bigger views. Another thing you can do is use [`.padding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/padding(_:_:)) instead of `Spacer().frame(width: 25)` — spacers are designed to expand to fill as much space as possible, so limiting its frame to `25` doesn't really make sense.

```
struct NewStruct: View {
    @State var someState = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Text1")
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 25)
            
            Button(action: {
                someState = !someState
            }, label: {
                    HStack {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "bolt.fill").resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 35, height: 35).cornerRadius(30).padding()
                            Text("Text1").foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "poweroff").resizable().frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                            Image(systemName: "power").resizable().frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    }
                    .background( /// here!
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).fill(Color.white)
                    )
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
   
        /// ZStacks are made for bigger views, like a red color that fills the screen.
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            NewStruct()
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: White background stretches to edge of screen]